# Getting Error creating window handle in C#.net application

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

Brief Overview of the project:

I am a relatively junior programmer.  My application is written in `C#.net` using `VS2008` and targeted to .net 3.5  It is a rather large program(by my standards) of approximately 200 forms + 30 classes and 50K lines of code.  One of the parts of the program imports data from a text file, calculates a bunch of stuff, and writes the result into an Access database.

The import process can often run for 20 minutes or more depending on the number of lines in the text file.  Eventually, the program crashes and I get the "Error Creating Window Handle error - always at different locations in my code.  As it runs, it seems to continually get slower as well. (Paging issues maybe?)  My OS is XP w/ SP3, 32 bit, 3Gig RAM if that matters.  The problem also happens on my W7 64 bit machine with 4Gig of RAM.

I have read up on the error and have done some detective work with task manager, and clearly I am experiencing a memory leak.  Here is some of the data I have gathered.

```
startup - memory usage = 48M / Handles = 428 / Threads = 17 / User Objects = 111

1 minute memory usage  = 65M / Handles = 520 / Threads = 22 / User Objects = 523

2 minutes memory usage = 81M / Handles = 520 / Threads = 19 / User Objects = 952

3 minutes memory sage = 98M / Handles = 510 / Threads = 19 / User Objects = 1359

4 minutes memory usage = 113M / Handles = 510 / Threads = 18 / User Objects = 1766
```

This continues until the program crashes..

From looking on the web for an answer. I was expecting to see the number of handles growing to cause the issue.  It appears that the issue is the number of User Objects is eating up my memory and maybe that is eventually causing the crash?  When the crash happens, the memory usage is generally between 450M and 600M.

I have tried adding some .Dispose() code in one of the classes I call multiple times during the data processing process, but that had no effect. (Maybe because I didn't do it right...)

1. Is the growing number of objects / memory usage causing the issue?
2. How can I find out what User Object (class or form?) is growing?
3. Once I find it, how do I fix it?

Any advise would be welcome.

Comment: Get hold of this - http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using main form-child form (or mdi form) structure and registering to the main form events, you may cause the closed child windows to live forever.

You may also use a memory profiler to see which objects are created excessively.

Comment: I am using a MDI form and the form where the code is running is a child of the main form.  The only child open at the time is the one that contains this code for the import process. It opens, asks for the file name and then process the data.  The form is very basic, but does contain a progress bar that alerts the user of the progress .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a memory profiler such as ANTS Memory Profiler. I've used it with great success to track down exactly which objects are growing.

They have a free trial and a [walkthrough](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough) to get started. They also have some good [technical papers](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/technical-papers/) that provide a better understanding on .NET memory leaks.